# Quelle est la prononciation correcte de « jadis » ?

Tags: prononciation

[Le Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/jadis) en dit ceci :

> (ja-dî ; aujourd'hui plusieurs, à tort, font sentir l's ; l's se lie : ja-di-z il y avait…)

[Le Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0047), par contre, dit ceci :

> (*s* se fait entendre)

Lequel de ces deux dictionnaires a raison ?

Comment: La vérité? Cela se voit plus souvent à l'écrit. Alors, on le dit pas souvent mais moi, je le dirais avec le s. Jadis et naguère=plus jolie avec le s, n'est-ce pas?

Answer (score 4):

Dans la dernière édition du dictionnaire de l'Académie française, qui fait sans doute autorité en la matière, il est précisé que le « *s* » se fait entendre : [jadis](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9J0047).

Note : @peanutjelly, la prononciation semble être guidée par l'usage. Comme l'écrivait Bossuet (cité par Littré à l'article « usage »): « L’usage, je le confesse, est appelé avec raison le père des langues ; le droit de les établir, aussi bien que de les régler, n’a jamais été disputé à la multitude ». Ainsi l'usage fait autorité. Il s'agit à présent de savoir qui est en droit d'identifier l'usage. J'ai, pour ma part, toujours entendu prononcer le « s » de jadis mais je ne suis pas accrédité pour identifier un usage de prononciation. C'est à l'Académie que l'on accorde cette autorité. Littré était également une référence, mais au dix-neuvième siècle. L'usage était différent. Il ne saurait y avoir de controverses entre le Littré et l'Académie française. Sans aucun doute Littré lui-même se rallierait aujourd'hui aux conclusions de l'Académie, dont il fit d'ailleurs partie.

Voyez cet [article](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/le-droit-et-lusage) sur le sujet.

Comment: Cela, je le dis bien déjà dans la description de la question. La question est, donc, plutôt de savoir pourquoi l'on devrait suivre la consigne du Littré au détriment de celle du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française ou vice versa.

Comment: @peanutjelly Toute "consigne" de prononciation trouvée dans un dictionnaire est illusoire si elle ne correspond pas déjà à la prononciation habituelle des ses lecteurs. Celle du Littré, probablement justifiée par le fait que le *S* final est étymologiquement la marque d'un pluriel, allait clairement à l'encontre d'une tendance qui s'est largement imposée aujourd'hui, même s'il doit encore peut-être se trouver des francophones natifs qui ne le prononcent pas.